# "Type Mismatch" when downloading image

Tags: vbscript, type-mismatch

I'm creating a program that helps me download images from a weather website, so I can get radar images. It creates a file named "radar" and then the time. For example if it was 5:00 PM it would be named `Radar500.png`.

The downloading works fine, but it says I have an error on a certain line:

```
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adTypeBinary = 1
if hour(time) > 12 then
  a=hour(time)-12
else        
  if hour(time) = 0 then
    a="12"
  else
    a=hour(time)
    b=minute(time)
  end if
end if
b=minute(time)
strSource = ""
strDest = "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\Overnight weather\radar"+a+"s"+b+".jpg"
WScript.Echo "path: "+strDest
'*****************************************************************
'** Download the image
strResult = GetImage(strSource, strDest)
If strResult = "OK" Then
  wscript.quit(0)
Else
  wscript.quit(1)
End If

Function GetImage(strPath, strDest)
  Dim objXMLHTTP, nF, arr, objFSO, objFile
  Dim objRec, objStream

  'create XMLHTTP component
  Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

  'get the image specified by strPath
  objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strPath, False
  objXMLHTTP.Send

  'check if retrieval was successful
  If objXMLHTTP.statusText = "OK" Then
    'create binary stream to write image output
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objStream.SavetoFile strDest, adSaveCreateOverwrite
    objStream.Close
    GetImage = "OK"
  Else
    GetImage = objXMLHTTP.statusText
  End If
End Function
```

They say the error is at Line 29 Char 1.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? You should be able to see more detail about what the error is, rather than just that there is an error. What type of error is it?

Comment: How do i debug... im new to this.. sorry..

Comment: OH! The error type is a type mismatch.

Comment: You don't specify any website to download from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strDest = "C:\Users\...\radar" & a & "s" & b & ".jpg"`. As per [MSDN: Addition Operator (+) (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd1e4aey(v=vs.84).aspx)

> Although you can also use the `+` operator to concatenate two
>   character strings, you should use the `&` operator for concatenation
>   to eliminate ambiguity. When you use the `+` operator, you may not be
>   able to determine whether addition or string concatenation will occur.
>
> The type of the expressions determines the behavior of the `+`
>   operator in the following way:
>
> ```
> If                                                   Then
> Both expressions are numeric                         Add
> Both expressions are strings                         Concatenate
> One expression is numeric and the other is a string  Error: type mismatch
> ```
>
> ...

Your script should work with next changes:

- assign a valid `strSource` value, e.g. `strSource = "http://www.goes.noaa.gov/FULLDISK/GMIR.JPG"`
- `objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strSource, False`. Note `strSource` instead of your `strDest`